# Changing FMX multi-platform style property at runtime

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, firemonkey-fm3

In my app I have a design time registered TStyleBook mostly with custom styles for panels (different colors). In this TStyleBook, at design time,  I've added an item, assigning the fill color, for several platforms, naming it '`panel_with_custom_color`'.

My question is how can I change the fill color for the '`panel_with_custom_color`' and with that changing the colors of all the TPanel objects that have the property

```
StyleLookup: panel_with_custom_color
```

Comment: This is not very clear. Double click on the StyleBook and the Style Editor opens up and from there you can change the Fill.Color. But I suspect you already did this... what is not working exactly?

Comment: Is there a way to change the existing Fill.Color programmatically?

Comment: This is still very ambiguous. Could you please show us (not in the comments, but in the question) what you are trying to do and achieve? You want to change the style at runtime? Are you using styles just to change background colors of panels?

Comment: guess this is old question, but could probably use FindStyleResource